# SQL Server query Builder wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have a query that I have developed in SQL and runs fine however when I place the query in the SQL Server (or .Net) query builder it builds it wrong. here is an example that is like the query I have written

This is what I write (and works)

```
Select Case when Table1.[Col 1] is null then Table2.[Col 1] Else Table1.[Col 1] END as 'col1' From 
(Select Sum(Table3.[Col 1]) as 'col 1', Table3.[groupby col] from Table3 Group by  Table3.[groupbycol]) as Table1 FULL OUTER JOIN (Select Sum(Table3.[Col 1]) as 'col 1', 'Total' as 'groupby col' from Table3) as Table2 ON Table1.[groupby col] = Table2.[groupby col]
```

but then if I open this in the sql or asp.net query builder the "improvements" it makes break the query and it now looks something like this

```
Select 
    Case 
       when Table1. 'Col 1' is null 
         then Table2. 'Col 1' 
         Else Table1. 'Col 1' 
    END as 'col1' 
From 
   (Select 
        Sum(Table3.[Col 1]) as 'col 1', 
        Table3.[groupby col] 
    from 
        Table3 
    group by  
        Table3.[groupbycol]) as Table1 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
   (Select 
        Sum(Table3.[Col 1]) as 'col 1', 
        'Total' as 'groupby col' 
    from Table3 as Table3_1) as Table2 ON Table1. 'groupby col' = Table2. 'groupby col'
```

which no longer works as it as it replaces [] with ' and adds a space in front of the column name and creates an alias for Table 3 in the second query and then does not assign that alias to the other times the table is used

Anyone knows what is causing this as it may become annoying if every time I open a query builder it may mess up the query

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String literals as column aliases are on the [deprecation list](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx) for SQL Server. Although not a portable syntax I have always been a fan of the `Alias = Expression` syntax in SQL Server. Aaron Bertrand makes a pretty good case for it too in his article [Bad Habits to Kick : Using AS instead of = for column aliases](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases).

With this in mind I would rewrite the entire query as:

```
SELECT  Col1 = ISNULL(table1.Col1, table2.Col1)
FROM    (   SELECT  Col1 = SUM(table3.[Col 1]),
                    GroupByCol = Table3.[groupby col]
            FROM    Table3
        ) table1
        FULL OUTER JOIN
        (   SELECT  Col1 = SUM(table3.[Col 1]),
                    GroupByCol = 'Total'
            FROM    Table3
        ) table2
            ON Table1.GroupByCol = Table2.GroupByCol;
```

Or

```
SELECT  ISNULL(table1.Col1, table2.Col1) AS Col1
FROM    (   SELECT  SUM(table3.[Col 1]) AS Col1,
                    Table3.[groupby col] AS GroupByCol
            FROM    Table3
        ) AS table1
        FULL OUTER JOIN
        (   SELECT  SUM(table3.[Col 1]) AS Col1,
                    'Total' AS GroupByCol
            FROM    Table3
        ) AS table2
            ON Table1.GroupByCol = Table2.GroupByCol;
```

I also suspect you can actually achieve the result you are after using [ROLLUP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT  Col1 = SUM(table3.[Col 1]),
        GroupByCol = ISNULL(Table3.[groupby col], 'Total')
FROM    Table3  
GROUP BY Table3.[groupby col] 
WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: I did not know that strings were depreciated in sql (in fact I thought it was good practice to use them haha) but I think I will stick with the as over = just because that's what everyone else I work with does